# How to generate coefficient subscript automatically in an equation

Tags: equations, subscripts

Is there any way that we could generate coefficient subscript automatically in an equation in latex? Such as 1,2,3 in

```
y = \beta_{1}x_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{2} + \beta_{3}x_{3}
```

, so that later, when I would like to insert a variable in the middle of the equation, I don't have to change all the subscripts after the variable.

Comment: This is very unclear, but you can get started with learning how to use `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 1):

Here use `\stepai` to step and print the autoindex, and `\theai` to just print the current value of the autoindex.  The autoindex is reset at the beginning of every math.

It achieves the desired behavior that, if you edit the equation and add an additional term in the middle (using `\stepai`), it will renumber the indices to preserve an ascending sequence.

To my pleasant surprise, this even works inside of `align` style environments, and resets the counter with each new line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{autoindex}
\everymath{\setcounter{autoindex}{0}}
\newcommand\stepai{\stepcounter{autoindex}\theautoindex}
\newcommand\theai{\theautoindex}
\begin{document}
\[
y = \beta_{\stepai}x_{\theai} 
  + \beta_{\stepai}x_{\theai} 
  + \beta_{\stepai}x_{\theai}
\]
$
y = \beta_{\stepai}x_{\theai} 
  + \beta_{\stepai}x_{\theai} 
  + \beta_{\stepai}x_{\theai}
$
\begin{align}
x &= \alpha_{\stepai}x_{\theai} 
  + \alpha_{\stepai}x_{\theai} 
  + \alpha_{\stepai}x_{\theai}\\
y &= \beta_{\stepai}x_{\theai} 
  + \beta_{\stepai}x_{\theai} 
  + \beta_{\stepai}x_{\theai}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Steven, it is great. Only one quick question, do you know how to use it in `split`? I found it would begin a new circle after a new line begins, but due to a large number of variables, I have to use split to display the equation in multiple lines. Thanks.

Comment: @Jacob2309 This is a problem.  I can globally save the value of the index and restore it...but the problem with that is that the `amsmath` environments compile with two passes, so that what would be expected to be indices 1,2,3, end up as 4,5,6.  The only workaround, using the above approach is to invoke, after \\ associated with the `split`, the command `\setcounter{autoindex}{<current value>}` to restore it for the 2nd line, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the point. Sounds good. Let me have a try.